# How to use the correct "FILTER HOOK"

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook-woocommerce

I would like to replace the image source in the code below:

```php
$placeholder = apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=' );

$html = sprintf( '<img%1$s src="%4$s" data-lazy-src=%2$s%3$s>', $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3], $placeholder );

$html_noscript = sprintf( '<noscript><img%1$s src=%2$s%3$s></noscript>', $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3] );
```

I've written this code to change it, but it's not working. What's wrong?

```php
function add_change_image_lazyload ( $output ) {
    $output = 'http://example.com/image.svg';
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', 'add_change_image_lazyload' );
```

Comment: Where did you place this code ? It should works

Comment: @AlexVand I have put the code in the function of the theme I'm using but I do not see the change of the image.

Comment: Could you add `var_dump($placeholder);` just after `$placeholder = apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=' );` in the plugin file. and tell me what is printed. Just after that remove the var_dump that we added.

Comment: @AlexVand This code:               $placeholder = apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=' ); . They are in the wp-rocket file. Did you mean I will add here?

Comment: Yes, i mean exactly that. But you should remove the line I tell you to add after.You can test without fear, it will only show what is in the variable placeholder.

Comment: An error code is repeated as follows  string(80) "http://example.com/image.svg"

Answer (score 1):

The way to change the spinner/loading image is :

```
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', function( $placeholder ) {
    $placeholder = 'your-spinner-url-here';
    return $placeholder;
} );
```

Code goes in your active theme/child functions.php